# Text data is not getting bind to html elements through jquery code only in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to bind text data to html elements through a jquery using particular element id but data is not getting bind only in chrome browser, same functionality is  properly working in other browsers like Firefox and IE. Following is my code please tell me solution if you have any.

```
var reqSegment1 = $('Segment', FlightReq);

$("#spOrgCity").html($('DepartureLocation', reqSegment1[0]).text());
$("#spDestCity").html($('ArrivalLocation', reqSegment1[0]).text());

if (tripType == "oneway") {
    $("#onewaydiv").attr("style", "display:block;");
    $("#rnddiv").attr("style", "display:none;");
}
else {
    $("#onewaydiv").attr("style", "display:block;");
    $("#rnddiv").attr("style", "display:block;");
}
```

Above code works properly for other browsers than chrome. I am unable to investigate what is actual problem if it is working with other browsers. Is it jquery conflict issue or something else.

Comment: Note, just use $("#onewaydiv").show() and $("#onewaydiv").hide() :)

Comment: I have tried by using $("#onewaydiv").show() and $("#onewaydiv").hide()  but still same problem

Comment: To ask the very obvious (and I apologise in advance for it), have you tried Ctrl+F5ing a couple of times? Chrome has a habit of caching JavaScript for longer than you'd expect/want.

Comment: Allmost time when i change anything to code I try to view it using Ctrl+F5

Comment: Just to double check there isn't a caching problem: in Chrome, press F12 to bring up the dev console, hit the settings cog in the bottom right hand corner and check the disable cache checkbox. Now reload your page.

Comment: Hey I have just placed all my above code in jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /*Here I placed code*/ }); and its worked.